# Setting nulls as 0, then using 0 in an operator?

Tags: sql

So I have the below code

```
SELECT PICK_SO_NUMBER, CUSTOMER, SO_PRODUCT, DO_QUANTITY, DO_PACKING, DO_DATE,
COALESCE(INVOICED_QTY, 0) AS INVOICED_QTY, 
DO_QUANTITY-INVOICED_QTY AS NOT_INVOICED, 
INVOICE_PACKING 
FROM VW_TRAFFIC_PO_SIDE
WHERE  DO_QUANTITY > INVOICED_QTY OR (INVOICED_QTY IS NULL AND DO_QUANTITY IS NOT NULL)
```

The line below the coalesce, is suppose to subtract the DO_QUANTITY from INVOICED_QTY, however when INVOICED_QTY is NULL, it no longer subtracts by 0, it subtracts by null, and thus the new column returns nulls where INVOICED_QTY is null

I tried multiple things: tried coalesce to a case, writing the coalesce as INVOICED and then using INVOICED in the subtraction expression, I tried using the coalesce in the same line as the subtraction (without comma in between, I felt this was the solution that would work best, but couldn't get it to compile)

Comment: In what situations is `INVOICED_QTY` null? Why ever?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *just a guess*, the OP inserts a record without a value in that field and which has no default value.

Comment: because the query is showing when the user (of the system) does not enter in an invoice, yet they receive a delivery...this query is designed to show when people forgot to invoice, or invoice the wrong amount per a delivery...when someone does not enter an invoice, the field is left blank, and thus, a null is assigned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gets confusing when you use the same alias 'invoiced_qty' in the select-list and in the WHERE clause.  The value in the subtraction is the raw column value, not the coalesced value from the previous select-list item.  The same is true in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT PICK_SO_NUMBER, CUSTOMER, SO_PRODUCT, DO_QUANTITY, DO_PACKING, DO_DATE,
       COALESCE(INVOICED_QTY, 0) AS INVOICED_QTY, 
       DO_QUANTITY - COALESCE(INVOICED_QTY, 0) AS NOT_INVOICED, 
       INVOICE_PACKING 
  FROM VW_TRAFFIC_PO_SIDE
 WHERE DO_QUANTITY > INVOICED_QTY
    OR (INVOICED_QTY IS NULL AND DO_QUANTITY IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: ah good point, that's my mistake, the where clause was written days before i needed to add the NOT_INVOICED, and i didn't think to go back and review it.

Answer (score 3):

you can't use `ALIAS` on the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT  PICK_SO_NUMBER, 
        CUSTOMER, 
        SO_PRODUCT, 
        DO_QUANTITY, 
        DO_PACKING, 
        DO_DATE,
        COALESCE(INVOICED_QTY, 0) AS INVOICED_QTY, 
        DO_QUANTITY-INVOICED_QTY AS NOT_INVOICED, 
        INVOICE_PACKING 
FROM    VW_TRAFFIC_PO_SIDE
-- note that INVOICE_QTY in WHERE  DO_QUANTITY > INVOICED_QTY
-- does not compare the result of COALESCE(INVOICED_QTY, 0)
-- but to the original value of INVOICE_QTY
WHERE  DO_QUANTITY > COALESCE(INVOICED_QTY, 0) OR 
        (INVOICED_QTY IS NULL AND DO_QUANTITY IS NOT NULL)
```

the reason is as follows:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

the `WHERE` clause comes after the `SELECT` (*which the setting of ALIAS takes place*) clause.

but if you really want to use that alias, wrap it in a subquery, eg

```
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    SELECT  PICK_SO_NUMBER, 
            CUSTOMER, 
            SO_PRODUCT, 
            DO_QUANTITY, 
            DO_PACKING, 
            DO_DATE,
            COALESCE(INVOICED_QTY, 0) AS INVOICED_QTY, 
            DO_QUANTITY-INVOICED_QTY AS NOT_INVOICED, 
            INVOICE_PACKING 
    FROM    VW_TRAFFIC_PO_SIDE
) s
WHERE    DO_QUANTITY > INVOICED_QTY OR 
        (INVOICED_QTY IS NULL AND DO_QUANTITY IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your rationale for aliases being invalid in `WHERE`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit on this case `INVOICED_QTY` is valid because it (*the column*) does exist. but let's say `COALESCE(INVOICED_QTY, 0) AS INVOICED_QTY_NEW`, the alias `INVOICED_QTY_NEW` can't be used.

Comment: I know it's invalid; I said I don't understand your _rationale_ for why this is the case, i.e. what does `WHERE` coming lexically after `SELECT` have to do with it?